# JS function stuck in loop

Tags: javascript

So, here's my function: It's supposed to extract links from input. (start at http or something like that and end at " "). The problem is that I can't debug how well this function works, because it stucks in loop. I've tried to check the reason why, still can't tell.

```
 function linkify(input)
    {
        if (input === undefined || input == null)

        return input;

        var tinput = input;
        var urlextr = "";
        var url = [""];
        var num = 0;

        //search for "http://" first
        while(tinput.match(/http:\/\//gi) != null)
        {
            console.log("http");
            urlextr=tinput.substring(tinput.search("http://"));
            urlextr=urlextr.substring(0,urlextr.search(" "));
            url[num] = urlextr;
            url[num+1] = urlextr;
            num = num + 2;
            tinput = tinput.replace(urlextr,"");
        }

        //search for "https://"
        while(tinput.match(/https:\/\//gi) != null)
        {
            console.log("https");
            urlextr=tinput.substring(tinput.search("https://"));
            urlextr=urlextr.substring(0,urlextr.search(" "));
            url[num] = urlextr;
            url[num+1] = urlextr;
            num = num + 2;
            tinput = tinput.replace(urlextr,"");
        }

        //search for "ftp://" (Why not?)
        while(tinput.match(/ftp:\/\//gi) != null)
        {
            console.log("ftp");
            urlextr=tinput.substring(tinput.search("ftp://"));
            urlextr=urlextr.substring(0,urlextr.search(" "));
            url[num] = urlextr;
            url[num+1] = urlextr;
            num = num + 2;
            tinput = tinput.replace(urlextr,"");
        }

        //search for "www.*" (Must be last!)
        while(tinput.match(/www./gi) != null)
        {
            console.log("www");
            urlextr=tinput.substring(tinput.search("www."));
            urlextr=urlextr.substring(0,urlextr.search(" "));
            url[num] = urlextr;
            url[num+1] = urlextr;
            num = num + 2;
            tinput = tinput.replace(urlextr,"");
        }
        console.log(url);
        return output;
    }
```

Comment: Unlikely. 2nd uses an html string. For me it should be: "random message and link www.stackoverflow.com www.youtube.com etc..." The function will read and then changes link as it's supposed to be later once all URLs are extracted. Without using any other JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have a string in which you have different urls separated with a space. The problem lies in

```
urlextr=urlextr.substring(0,urlextr.search(" "));
```

In case you are processing the last `URL` in your string it will always return an empty string, thus making the loop run indefinitely. To fix it you could do sth like below

```
urlextr=tinput.substring(tinput.search("http://"));
urlextr=urlextr.substring(0,urlextr.search(" "));
if (!urlextr) {
    url[num] = tinput.trim();
    break;
}
url[num] = urlextr;
url[num+1] = urlextr;
```

Comment: That worked, but it breaks function itself, since array have next order: every even number (0,2,4,6...) will have full URL, while every odd number will have a shortened URL, or how user wrote it.

Comment: `url[num] = urlextr;url[num+1] = urlextr;` here you are assigning the same value to array elements - you need to fix your code

Comment: Already fixed, thanks for helping though. I've came up with mine fix. So function perfectly separates things